# Have to use Task.Sleep to prevent Cosmos DB 429 error message

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm inserting from a batch execution around 2100 items in a cosmos DB. Those item represent a product detail taken from a supplier.

I'm saving them in a CosmosDB with the following code

```
 private async Task SaveProductToDbAsync(IList<ResponseItem> products, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using var client = new CosmosClient(_cosmosDbOptions.CosmosDbAccountEndpoint, _cosmosDbOptions.CosmosDbAccountKey);

        var database = client.GetDatabase(_cosmosDbOptions.CosmosDbDatabaseName);

        var container = database.GetContainer(_cosmosDbOptions.CosmosDbContainerId);

        int count = 0;
        int successInsert = 0;
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            item.id = Utility.ToGuid(item.pk);

            await container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.id), cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith(itemResponse =>
                     {
                         if (itemResponse.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                         {
                             successInsert++;
                             log.LogDebug($"CosmosDB Created item in Database with id: {item.id}");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             AggregateException innerExceptions = itemResponse.Exception.Flatten();
                             if (innerExceptions.InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault(
                                     innerEx => innerEx is CosmosException) is CosmosException cosmosException)
                             {
                                 log.LogError(
                                     $"CosmosDB Could not Create item in Database with id: {item.id}, StatusCode: {cosmosException.StatusCode}, Error: {cosmosException.Message}");
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 log.LogError(
                                     $"CosmosDB Could not Create item in Database with id: {item.id}, Error: {innerExceptions.InnerExceptions.FirstOrDefault()}");
                             }
                         }
                     }, cancellationToken);

            //This is to avoid 429 CosmosDB error messages
            await Task.Delay(80, cancellationToken);
            count++;
        }

        log.LogInformation($"Inserted {successInsert}/{count} products");
    }
```

If I don't put the Task.Delay(80) I got a ton of  429 errors.

But at the end of execution there're almost 3 minutes wasted waiting.. I'm running this code in a WebJob.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to guess how long to call Task.Delay. The Cosmos exception tells you.

```
try
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        await container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.id));
    }
}
catch (CosmosException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    {
        TimeSpan delay = (TimeSpan)ex.RetryAfter;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        await container.CreateItemAsync(record, new PartitionKey(id));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add throttling-retry settings when you init your CosmosClient like this:

```cs
CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(cosmosDbEndpoint, tokenCredential)
.WithConnectionModeDirect()
.WithThrottlingRetryOptions(maxRetryWaitTimeOnThrottledRequests: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests: 9);

var client = clientBuilder.Build();
```

This way, the client will handle 429-retries internally for you and only error out once the defined threshold have been exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

As answered @MarkBrown and @Silent, you should use the RetryAfter property and configure MaxRetry properties to prevent looping uselessly.

I had implementation that worked around this point :

```
    private async Task<U> SafeGetAsync<U>(IBaseEntityModel input, CancellationToken token, int retryQuery = 0)
            where U : class, IBaseEntityModel
{
try
{
    // request your data
}
catch (DocumentClientException dce)
{
    switch ((int)dce.StatusCode)
    {
        case 429: // RequestTooLarge exception - RU consumption - Should be handled by CosmosDBEventStore service from socle
            Thread.Sleep(dce.RetryAfter);
            break;
        case 408: // RequestTimeout exception - CPU Usage
        default:
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(++retryQuery));
            //Console.WriteLine("UpsertAsync Failed ({0}) : {1}", dce.InnerException.GetType(), dce.InnerException.Message);
            break;
    }
    return await SafeGetAsync<U>(input, token, retryQuery);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogError($"Failed Operation - GetAsync : " +
        $"Message = {ex.Message} " +
        $"StackTrace = {ex.StackTrace} ");
}
```

Note that I also catch 408 issue that may happen if you overuse that CosmosDb, comparing his scaling and your usage.

And configuration bellow :

```
public static void ConfigureSocleServiceOptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
{
    services.Configure<CosmosDBEventStoreOptions>(option);
    services.PostConfigure<CosmosDBEventStoreOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.RetryCount = 10;
    });
    services.PostConfigure<ExtraCosmosDBEventStoreOptions>(options =>
    {
        // RetryOptions
        options.MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb:EventStore:RetryOptions:MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests").Get<int?>();
        options.MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb:EventStore:RetryOptions:MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds").Get<int?>();
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm performing a POST not a get.. but I think it's similar

Comment: Yeah, same logic